# CSS3 transition is delaying AngularJS redrawing of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, css

I have few buttons and i have this transition for them when you're hovering them:

`@include prefix(transition,  background-color 300ms linear);`

When i click the button the `ng-repeat` directive is repeating some list associated with that particular button. But when i have the animation on AngularJS first shows both the lists (for the button that is clicked now, and the button that was previously clicked) and after 300ms (the time of the animation) it hides the first list.

When i remove the animation the lists switch immediately, but i want to have the animation.

Is there any fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: have a fiddle to prove it ?

Comment: i don't have a fiddle but i recorded a gif from the behavior http://www.gfycat.com/WildSlightAustrianpinscher